# Do operation where the column number is one of the operands?

Tags: python, numpy

Let say I have (5,5) array.
How can I do operation such that the column number is one of the operands f.e. if the array is all **zeros** then if i do :

```
 a + Col-num?
```

then the first column of the result will be all 1's, the second all 2's,...3's, 4's, all 5's

So the second ghost-operand is the column-number ?

Comment: You can transpose and enumerate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a+(np.arange(a.shape[1])+1)
```

output:

```
a = np.zeros((4,4))
a+(np.arange(a.shape[1])+1)
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that this would be a bit faster than the posted answers:

```
def f(c):
    col, arr = c
    return arr + (col + 1)
a = np.zeros((5, 5))
columnAdded = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, enumerate(a.T)).T
columnAdded
>>> array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])
```

Done in a `numpy` way as requested

Comment: `apply_along` is not a speed tool.  You can test that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
arr = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
columnAdded = [[x+i for i,x in enumerate(row)] for row in arr]
```

Or this using numpy:

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
print(arr+np.arange(1,1+len(arr[0])))
```

Comment: yeah, but in numpy way ;)

Comment: Here you go! :)